# Using try/catch blocks in unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Using VS's testing framework, I'm currently writing my tests like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething() 
{
    try
    {
        var someTestValue = _someTestClass.SomeTestMethod();            

        Assert.IsNotNull(someTestValue);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Assert.Fail(e.Message);
    }
}
```

My logic is that if an exception is thrown in `SomeTestMethod()`, I'll immediately terminate the test displaying the exception message through `Assert.Fail(e.Message)`.

The "normal way" of doing things would be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething() 
{
    var someTestValue = _someTestClass.SomeTestMethod();            

    Assert.IsNotNull(someTestValue);
}
```

Is my approach correct, or is the "normal way" correct? Am I writing redundant code ?

Comment: The test will fail if an exception is thrown. You don't need to catch the exception. On the other hand if you expect an exception you could use the `[ExpectedException(...)]` attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say this is redundant, yes.  If the exception is an unexpected result then the test fails.  Whether it fails by throwing an exception or by failing an Assert is treated the same way by the testing framework.  Basically, a failed test is a failed test.

Answer (score 2):

The testing framework will *already* fail the test if the test method throws an exception.  You're adding extra work for no added value.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing redundant code.  The Test method already traps exceptions and will fail the test method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting some exception, use this attribute:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(//Here the exception you expect))]  <------------
public void TestSomething() 
{
//Your test code
}
```

This means that if the tests throw this exception, will return as passed the tests.

If you don´t go to tests exceptions, then avoid try/catch blocks inside your tests. You will notice that something went wrong because the tests will fail ;)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial; there is an example unit test using the [expectedException()] attribute:
[Tutorial for ExpectedException Unit tests][1]

```
  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#BKMK_Writing_your_tests
```